# Using polar coordinates to show relationship between radii and areas

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

I want to show that the radius of a circle $r_c$, that has an area $A_c$ that is twice the area $A_p$ of a polar diagram, is equal to the quadratic mean of all values $r_p$ of the polar diagram.

I interpreted this as wanting to show:
$$
r_c = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r_p^2(\theta) d\theta}
$$

I know that I can define the following using polar coordinates:
$$
A_p = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r_p^2(\theta) d\theta
$$

However, after solving the following, I get a different answer:
\begin{align}
A_c &= 2A_p \\
\pi r_c^2 &= 2 \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r_p^2(\theta) d\theta \\
r_c &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r_p^2(\theta) d\theta}
\end{align}

I feel like I must have made a really silly mistake somewhere! This line of reasoning suggests that this would only be possible if the original areas were equal.

Comment: Well, the original statement that you're trying to prove cannot be correct. To see that, consider the case when the polar diagram is itself a circle. It also makes intuitive sense that the correct statement should be about $A_c = A_p$.

Comment: @tia Exactly! I just felt that perhaps I was missing something. The exact words of the problem is: Show that the radius of a circle, the area of which is twice the
area of a polar diagram, is equal to the quadratic mean of all the values
of r for that polar diagram.